# Change Location Mode From Battery Saving to High Accuracy android

Tags: android, location

How to Change Location Mode From Battery Saving to High Accuracy in android Programatically

[image]

Comment: You can't. Let the user do that

Comment: i need to turn on gps so im showing user to setting page if mode in battery saving meanse Location is showing ON but actually Gps is in OFF state

Comment: Instead of programmatically ways or user doing it manually, you can pop up a dialog that changes location mode with just one click. Please check [SettingsApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/SettingsApi)